# Alt+F2 set to "Activities" view in GNOME Shell, can't access the command prompt anymore

Tags: gnome

Today I discovered that my `gnome-shell` doesn't let me run commands using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> anymore. Both keys are now bound to the activity view, just like the left super key (Super_L).

The **Show the run command prompt** preference in the keyboard shortcuts system panel is already set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but this seems to make no difference.

As a result I have no way now to invoke the command prompt for the shell and I wonder if somebody else has the same problem.

I stumbled into this weird behavior *trying to configure the right Super key to work as the left one* and open the activity view. That effect proved impossible to achieve and Super_R keeps doing nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change keyboard shortcuts
Here's how:

1-[image: http://WWW.m5zn.com/img/?img=9589049d2d0e2c9.png]

2-[image: http://www.m5zn.com/img/?img=611312d6143bd4e.png]

3-[image: http://www.m5zn.com/img/?img=9d0093c55b1a064.png]

4-[image: http://www.m5zn.com/img/?img=a8e04b8fed5bfda.png]

5-[image: http://www.m5zn.com/img/?img=b1b8bc8c293f0a9.png]

6-[image: http://www.m5zn.com/img/?img=f4493a1b2bfabc9.png]

7-[image: http://www.m5zn.com/img/?img=cf7dec276e1bda5.png]
**

Comment: Please explain what you are doing in addition to adding the screenshots. Also, add screenshots that are in English to benefit the general public who are not efficient in Arabic.

Comment: @fossfreedom thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I already tried to tweak the keyboard settings, but nothing has changed: the **Run command** prompt doesn't show up, no matter the kybinding I assign to it and `Alt+F2` keeps bringing up Overlay mode...